# How to pass JQuery variable to a global one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, google-maps

I'm trying to retrieve data from JQuery function and pass it into global variables to use with Google Maps. These variables have to stay global, otherwise Google Maps don't work with them. I manage to get all data that I need from AJAX url and it logs perfectly but only inside Jquery function. If I log it outside of it, it's undefined. Is there anyway to pass those values to global variables?

```
function displayMarkers() {    
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitd, longtd);
    var name = titleName;
    createMarker(latlng, name);    
}  

var latitd;
var longtd;
var titleName;       

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#earthquakes').click(function() {    
        getQuakes();
    });

    function getQuakes() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=' + yesterDate + '&endtime=' + displayDate,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data.features, function(key, val) {
                    var coord = val.geometry.coordinates;
                    locationD = {
                        latd: coord[0],
                        lngd: coord[1]
                    };
                    latitd = locationD.latd;
                    longtd = locationD.lngd;
                    titleName = val.properties.title;

                    console.log(latitd, longtd);
                    console.log(titleName);    
                });
            }    
        });    
    }    
});
```

Comment: put definition of function out side Dom ready

Comment: Yes you are access it wrongly. You will get lat,long values only after ajax success. then and then you use those variables in another function

Comment: Thanks for voting me down, but none of "duplicate" questions are relevant to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
var latitd;
var longtd;
var titleName;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#earthquakes').click(function () {
        getQuakes();
    });
});

function getQuakes() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=' + yesterDate + '&endtime=' + displayDate,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.features, function (key, val) {
                var coord = val.geometry.coordinates;
                locationD = {
                    latd: coord[0],
                    lngd: coord[1]
                };
                latitd = locationD.latd;
                longtd = locationD.lngd;
                titleName = val.properties.title;

                console.log(latitd, longtd);
                console.log(titleName);

                //Call this function to display here after success ajax
                displayMarkers();
            });
        }
    });
}

function displayMarkers() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitd, longtd);
    var name = titleName;
    createMarker(latlng, name);
}
```

Comment: Nope it sill doesn't pass those values outside of the Ajax function. It gives me "undefined"

Comment: Please check displayMarkers();  function position. I changed that one.

Comment: Now it does work, thank you so much you saved me!

Answer (score -1):

Add an `async:false` to your ajax request.

Comment: Doesn't really change anything. I added it after url:  line

Comment: if it's not working you can pass the latlang as a parameter to your displayMarkers.